# On click cursor adapter

Tags: android, list, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to create a android application that displays book objects from a SQLite database .I am trying to create an on click listener for a cursor adapter using onItemClick. When the user clicks on a specific row of the list I am trying to get the price of the book to appear. However I cannot workout the correct syntax to display it.

Here is my BookListAdapter class

```
    public class BookListFragment extends ListFragment {

        private Bookstore mBookstore;
        private List<Book> mBooks;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ContentResolver resolver = this.getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.bookstore.app.model.BookContentProvider/books");
            Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

            String[] from = new String[] {
                "title", "author", "year" 
            };
            int [] to = new int[] {
                R.id.list_item_book_title_textView,
                R.id.list_item_book_author_textView,
                R.id.list_item_book_year_textView
            };

        // CREATE THE ADAPTER USING THE CURSOR POINTING TO THE DATABASE
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_book, cursor, from, to, 0);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            Activity activity = getActivity();

            mBookstore = Bookstore.getInstance(activity);
            mBooks = mBookstore.getBooks();

            ListAdapter adapter1 = new BookListAdapter(activity, mBooks);

            setListAdapter(adapter1);



        }



    }
```

And here is my BooklistAdapter class

```
public class BookListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> implements ListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Book> mBooks;

    public BookListAdapter(Context context, List<Book> books) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_book, books);

        mContext = context;
        mBooks = books;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            // create a new list item view
            Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_book, null);
        }



        // customize layout for book
        Book bk = mBooks.get(position);

        TextView titleView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_book_title_textView);
        TextView authorView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_book_author_textView);
        TextView PriceView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_book_price_textView);
        TextView yearView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_book_year_textView);

        titleView.setText(bk.getTitle());
        authorView.setText(bk.getAuthor());
        yearView.setText("" + bk.getYear());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I am unsure where I would put something like

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position)
    {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        yearView.setText("" + bk.getYear());
    }
```

in order to display the specific price for that row targeted by the cursor. 
Any help would be very much appreciated.

If there is any confusion please comment and I will clarify.

Comment: why do you call setListAdapter twice?

Comment: Apologies that wasn't meant to be there.